# Why would localhost:8080 give a 404 error?

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat

Does the 404 error localhost:8080 mean that Tomcat can't find the index.html or that it is down completely?

In my case the netstat command shows there is something listening on port 8080

```
$ netstat -an | grep 8080
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Or could this be something broken with Tomcat configuration? If it matters in this case, I use Ubuntu.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: If it was down completely you wouldn't get an HTTP response code, you'd get a connection timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard of Tomcat problems with machines using ipv6. Try to blacklist the `ipv6` module on `/etc/modprobe.d` directory and reboot to see if it binds correctly.

Comment: @coredump How do I "blacklist" the ipv6 module?  And also, what is it for?  Maybe my other applications will need it?

Comment: @genadinik unless you have an application that is using ipv6 this will not be a problem. Create a file inside the mentioned directory and write `blacklist ipv6` on it.

Comment: @coredump before I reboot - I added the line to blacklist.conf - is that the right file?  There were a few variations on the blacklist file name in that directory.  Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if that's the advisable thing to do. Create a new file inside the directory like `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ipv6.conf` and add `blacklist ipv6` inside that file. Just that.

Comment: Thanks - giving it a try.... :) lets see if I survive to tell the tale.

Comment: You can use `sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1` to disable IPv6.  You can also disable IPv6 on individual interfaces.  I created a `/etc/sysctl.d/80-disable-ipv6.conf` file with all `disable.ipv6` values set to `0` when I wanted IPv6 disabled.

Comment: That didn't end up working.  I have a feeling I need to get rid of my current Tomcat install (version 7) and get version 6. Any thoughts on the best way to go about doing that? :)

Answer (score 2):

This error just means the default page (not necessarily index.html) cannot be found. Have a look at your tomcat log files (tomcat-dir/logs/* ) for details.